# return yes or no from switch material-ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, toggle, togglebutton

hi i am building a form and i am able to return the values of my other inputs with my onchange and state. but when i try implementing the switch i get nothing back not even a true or false. how would i get the switch to return the yes or no labels when toggled?
here is the material-ui component that i will use

material.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import FormGroup from '@material-ui/core/FormGroup';
import Switch from '@material-ui/core/Switch';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';


export default function CustomizedSwitches() {

  return (
<FormGroup>
  <Typography component="div">
    <Grid component="label" container alignItems="center" spacing={1}>
      <Grid item>No</Grid>
      <Grid item>
        <AntSwitch />
      </Grid>
      <Grid item>Yes</Grid>
    </Grid>
  </Typography>
</FormGroup>
);
}
```

and here is how i am handling inputs in my form

form.js

```
class App extends Component {

// constructor
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);


    // initial state
    this.state = {
        formValues                : {},//this is where i store my input values
    };

 // i use this to submit info
this.submitInformation        = this.submitInformation.bind(this);

  }


  handleChange(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const isCheckbox = event.target.type==='checkbox'; //implementing this does not work why??


    let formValues = this.state.formValues
    let name = event.target.name;
    let value = isCheckbox ? event.target.checked : event.target.value; //is the problem here??

    formValues[name] = value

    this.setState({formValues});
  }



 async submitInformation(event){

    event.preventDefault();
    alert('You have submitted the form.')

    let sharePointStructure = {
        response                                     : this.state.formValues[false],
        ToolName                                  : this.state.formValues["ToolName"],
}


  return (
  <div className="App">
    <div >

      <form className="float-container" onSubmit = {this.submitInformation}>

          <div>
             
              <CustomizedSwitches 
              name="response" 
              onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} 
              checked={this.state.formValues["response"]}/>
          </div>
       <form/>
    </div>
```

)

Answer (score 0):

you are mutating the state which can cause some problems.
try this instead by making a shallow copy of state:

```
handleChange(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const isCheckbox = event.target.type==='checkbox'; //implementing this does not work why??


    let formValues = {...this.state.formValues} //make a shallow copy of formValues
    let name = event.target.name;
    let value = isCheckbox ? event.target.checked : event.target.value; //is the problem here??

    formValues[name] = value // then mutate the copied state

    this.setState({formValues});
}
```